# How to Create Dynamic SQL With Pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data that looks like this.

[image]

I want to pivot it to look like this.

[image]

I'm testing the SQL script below.  It doesn't throw and error, but it doesn't actually do anything either.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    declare @startDate datetime
    declare @endDate datetime        
    set @startDate = '09/10/2017'
    set @endDate = '10/31/2017'

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.AsOfDate) 
            FROM [UNION_SUMMARY] c
            WHERE c.AsOfDate Between @startDate And @endDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT PID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT PID,  
                Reportable_Amount,
                AsOfDate
                from [UNION_SUMMARY]
            WHERE AsOfDate Between @startDate And @endDate
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Reportable_Amount)
                for AsOfDate in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
print @query

exec sp_executesql @query, N'@startDate date, @endDate date', @startDate = @startDate, @endDate = @endDate;
```

Sample...

```
--drop table dynamic_sql
CREATE TABLE dynamic_sql (
    AsOfDate datetime,
    Portfolio nvarchar(255),
    PID nvarchar(5),
    Reportable_Amount decimal(32,15),
    TBL varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('12/29/2017', 'Bonds', 'IUD', '-711.56', 'Mortgage');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('12/29/2017', 'Bonds', 'IUD', '-709.34', 'Mortgage');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('3/30/2018', 'Retail Loans', 'PPU', '-707.13', 'Commercial');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID,  Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('3/30/2018', 'Retail Loans', 'PPU', '-704.93', 'Commercial');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('3/30/2018', 'Retail Loans', 'PPU', '-702.73', 'Commercial');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('4/30/2018', 'FX', 'DGT', '-700.54', 'Foreign');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('4/30/2018', 'FX', 'DGT', '-698.36', 'Foreign');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('4/30/2018', 'FX', 'DGT', '-696.19', 'Foreign');

INSERT INTO dynamic_sql (AsOfDate, Portfolio, PID, Reportable_Amount, TBL)
VALUES ('4/30/2018', 'FX', 'DGT', '-694.02', 'Foreign');
```

Comment: Dates in the sample data are not in the range given in the query. Changing the dates gives the correct result.

Comment: Like @satishcse writes. Change your enddate to 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following to get the "Grand Total" row too:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    declare @startDate datetime
    declare @endDate datetime        
    set @startDate = '09/10/2017'
    set @endDate = '10/31/2018'

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), c.AsOfDate, 101)) 
            FROM dynamic_sql c
            WHERE c.AsOfDate Between @startDate And @endDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @NulltoZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @NulltoZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(['+convert(varchar(10), AsOfDate, 101)+'],0) AS [AsOfDate]' 
FROM dynamic_sql GROUP BY convert(varchar(10), AsOfDate, 101) FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)

print @NulltoZeroCols

set @query1 = 'INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE SELECT PID, ' + @NulltoZeroCols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT PID,  
                ISNULL(cast(Reportable_Amount as numeric(5,2)), 0) Reportable_Amount,
                convert(varchar(10), AsOfDate, 101) AsOfDate
                from dynamic_sql
            WHERE AsOfDate Between @startDate And @endDate
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Reportable_Amount)
                for AsOfDate in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
print @query1

set @query2 = 'SELECT ''Grand Total'' PID, ' + @cols + ' into temp_table from 
            (
                select  convert(varchar(10), AsOfDate, 101) AsOfDate,
                ISNULL(cast(Reportable_Amount as numeric(5,2)), 0) Reportable_Amount from dynamic_sql
            WHERE AsOfDate Between @startDate And @endDate
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(Reportable_Amount)
                for AsOfDate in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
print @query2
exec sp_executesql @query2, N'@startDate date, @endDate date', @startDate = @startDate, @endDate = @endDate;
exec sp_executesql @query1 , N'@startDate date, @endDate date', @startDate = @startDate, @endDate = @endDate;
select * from TEMP_TABLE ORDER BY LEN(PID)
drop table TEMP_TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!!